Running .NET MAUI application on windows machine throwing exception from external code in Windows specific platform file
As the title suggests I'm having trouble with running my .NET MAUI app on Windows all of a sudden. I am getting the following exception:
Exception thrown: 'System.TypeInitializationException' in forecAstIng.dll
An exception of type 'System.TypeInitializationException' occurred in forecAstIng.dll but was not handled in user code
The type initializer for '<Module>' threw an exception.
From the MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp() function in the automatically generated platform specific file App.xaml.cs that is created when starting a MAUI project:
using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;

// To learn more about WinUI, the WinUI project structure,
// and more about our project templates, see: http://aka.ms/winui-project-info.

namespace forecAstIng.WinUI
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Provides application-specific behavior to supplement the default Application class.
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : MauiWinUIApplication
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Initializes the singleton application object.  This is the first line of authored code
        /// executed, and as such is the logical equivalent of main() or WinMain().
        /// </summary>
        public App()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        protected override MauiApp CreateMauiApp() => MauiProgram.CreateMauiApp();
    }

}

MauiProgram.cs:
using forecAstIng.View;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using CommunityToolkit.Maui;
using forecAstIng.Services;

namespace forecAstIng
{
    public static class MauiProgram
    {
        public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
        {
            var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
            builder
                .UseMauiApp<App>()
                .UseMauiCommunityToolkit()
                .ConfigureFonts(fonts =>
                {
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Regular.ttf", "OpenSansRegular");
                    fonts.AddFont("OpenSans-Semibold.ttf", "OpenSansSemibold");
                });

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<DataService>();

            builder.Services.AddSingleton<ForecastsViewModel>();
            builder.Services.AddSingleton<MainPage>();

            builder.Services.AddTransient<MorePageViewModel>();
            builder.Services.AddTransient<MorePage>();

            #if DEBUG
                builder.Logging.AddDebug();
            #endif

            return builder.Build();
        }
    }
}

csproj:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
        <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
        <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
        <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->

        <!-- Note for MacCatalyst:
        The default runtime is maccatalyst-x64, except in Release config, in which case the default is maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64.
        When specifying both architectures, use the plural <RuntimeIdentifiers> instead of the singular <RuntimeIdentifier>.
        The Mac App Store will NOT accept apps with ONLY maccatalyst-arm64 indicated;
        either BOTH runtimes must be indicated or ONLY macatalyst-x64. -->
        <!-- For example: <RuntimeIdentifiers>maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers> -->

        <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
        <RootNamespace>forecAstIng</RootNamespace>
        <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
        <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

        <!-- Display name -->
        <ApplicationTitle>forecAstIng</ApplicationTitle>

        <!-- App Identifier -->
        <ApplicationId>com.companyname.forecasting</ApplicationId>

        <!-- Versions -->
        <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
        <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
        <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
        <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <!-- App Icon -->
        <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="32,32" />

        <!-- Splash Screen -->
        <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

        <!-- Images -->
        <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />

        <!-- Custom Fonts -->
        <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

        <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
        <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <None Remove="resources\images\source.md" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Maui" Version="9.0.3" />
        <PackageReference Include="CommunityToolkit.Mvvm" Version="8.3.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="8.0.82" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="8.0.82" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
      <MauiXaml Update="View\SearchPrompt.xaml">
        <Generator>MSBuild:Compile</Generator>
      </MauiXaml>
    </ItemGroup>

</Project>

I am on dotnet8 as I believe the build targets show as well.
I am not sure if it is relevant, but just before I started getting this exception I updated the nuget packages I use for my project, because I was having other issues with weird exceptions on windows inside of my program. I use these packages:

CommunityToolkit.Maui

CommunityToolkit.Mvvm

Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug

Microsoft.Maui.Controls

Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility

Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks

Newtonsoft.Json



What's your .net version? Could you please show the csproj file and mauiprogram.cs?

Thank you for the comment, I addded the requested information

Do you mean there was no exception before updating the nuget packages? Have you tried deleting obj and bin multiple times and restarting VS?

I did everything you mentioned just now and nothing helped, still the same exception. Yes, no exception before updating but I'm not sure which ones I updated or if that had anything to do with the error or it was just coincidence. In the staging ground someone suggested the issue might be with Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks but I don't know what.

I think the error is caused by the package version conflict. After checking, the Newtonsoft.Json package was last updated on 3/8/2023, so the package you updated recently should not be this one. In addition, the four packages Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug, Microsoft.Maui.Controls, and Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility are automatically downloaded when creating a project. And Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks cannot change the version, so thet are also excluded.

Finally, CommunityToolkit.Maui, CommunityToolkit.Mvvm is left. Both packages have recently released new versions, so you can try to temporarily downgrade their versions to see if the error disappears.

Thank you!! Community.Toolkit.Mvvm was the culprit, I first downgraded community.toolkit.maui with no success but then going 8.3.0 to 8.2.2 in .mvvm package made the error go away

Congratulations! I edited my solution as an answer, you can check it out.

Since the error occurs after updating the Nuget package, it occurs because of a package version conflict.
Exclude Newtonsoft.Json, because it was last updated on 3/8/2023.
Exclude Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug, Microsoft.Maui.Controls and Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility, because they are automatically downloaded when creating a project. And Microsoft.NET.ILLink.Tasks cannot change the version.
So the problem is with CommunityToolkit.Mauiand CommunityToolkit.Mvvm, both packages have recently released new versions.
The problem was eventually solved by downgrading the version of the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm package from 8.3.0 to 8.2.2. I didn't currently find a issue on the Maui Github about version conflicts of the CommunityToolkit.Mvvm package, you can post this issue to Maui Github.

the community toolkit team has provided workaround here https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/dotnet/issues/923
